# Fire an event when a process' window is closed, not when the process has exited

Tags: c#, .net, windows, process

I start a process with:

```
var process = Process.Start("somestuff.bat");
```

However, when somestuff is done, it does not kill the process, only the window is closed, so naturally:

```
process.Exited += ...
```

will never fire off.

So, is there a way to somehow get the window handle, or whatever is convenient of the `process` and fire off a method when that window is closed?

Comment: You want to kill process while window closing?

Comment: No, window get closed, but the process is still running, I want to kill the process when the window is closed (which I don't know when will happen)

Comment: so here you can use WindowClosed or WindowClosing event .. you know about these event ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Use this make closing event..
```

XML Closing="Window_Closing"

```
private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgse)
{
    KillProcess();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set something on the process to make it fire the event

```
var process = Process.Start("somestuff.bat");
process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
process.Exited += .. // note here, this runs in the process thread not the UI
```

Exited then fires

Answer (score -1):

Try this may this solve your problem

```
foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName(".exe"))
{
    process.Kill();
}
```